# Make jquery function start

Tags: jquery

I have some issues starting this function what am i doing wrong?

I want this to start writing when my menu has reached the section "topb".

This is the attempt from me:

```
var $el = $('.writer'),
    txt = $el.text(),
    txtLen = txt.length,
    timeOut,
    $topb = $('#topb'),
    char = 0;

$el.text('|');

if (topb.hasClass('active')) {
    (function typeIt() {
        var humanize = Math.round(Math.random() * (200 - 30)) + 30;
        timeOut = setTimeout(function () {
            char++;
            var type = txt.substring(0, char);
            $el.text(type + '|');
            typeIt();

            if (char == txtLen) {
                $el.text($el.text().slice(0, -1)); // remove the '|'
                clearTimeout(timeOut);
            }
        }, humanize);
    }())
};
```

This is the original function

```
var $el = $('.writer'),
    txt = $el.text(),
    txtLen = txt.length,
    timeOut,
    char = 0;

$el.text('|');

(function typeIt() {
    var humanize = Math.round(Math.random() * (200 - 30)) + 30;
    timeOut = setTimeout(function () {
        char++;
        var type = txt.substring(0, char);
        $el.text(type + '|');
        typeIt();

        if (char == txtLen) {
            $el.text($el.text().slice(0, -1)); // remove the '|'
            clearTimeout(timeOut);
        }
    }, humanize);
}())
};
```

Comment: $topb = $('#topb') and topb.hasClass('active'), you forgot about "$" sign.

Comment: @pushOk: true (already mentioned below), but that is the least of their problems as that code is never run again :)

Answer (score 1):

The original code uses a timer to repeat the operation until a certain condition is met (calls itself recursively). You have placed your `if` check outside of that, so it never runs.

Do your check inside the timer, so it is checked repeatedly. Like this:

```
var $el = $('.writer'),
    txt = $el.text(),
    txtLen = txt.length,
    timeOut,
    $topb = $('#topb'),
    char = 0;

$el.text('|');

(function typeIt() {
    if ($topb.hasClass('active')) {
        var humanize = Math.round(Math.random() * (200 - 30)) + 30;
        timeOut = setTimeout(function () {
            char++;
            var type = txt.substring(0, char);
            $el.text(type + '|');
            typeIt();

            if (char == txtLen) {
                $el.text($el.text().slice(0, -1)); // remove the '|'
                clearTimeout(timeOut);
            }
        }, humanize);
    }
    else{
        // do nothing but repeat the timer (e.g. after 2 seconds)
        timeOut = setTimeout(typeIt, 2000);
    }
}());
```

Comment: Okey but it dosent work even if i dosent use the if statement to start it @TrueBlueAussie

Comment: There may be more than one bug... This was a guideline to fix the obvious one. A JSFiddle example is usually the best way to demonstrate a problem like this. Then we can all guarantee it works *completely* :)

Comment: Ok i will test some more and se if i can fix it :) thank you for your awnser! @TrueBlueAussie

Comment: Note: There was a typo in my example... now fixed (a `$` was missing on `$topb.hasClass('active')`)